# "Item not found". I'm unable to test my own in-app billing even though everything is correct

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-console

I've implemented an in-app in my app successfully and published it to an Internal testing track. I tried testing the in-app billing myself, but it keeps saying "Item not found". I've setup my products correctly, they're all active, I added my license key and my code has no issues. Why am I unable to test my own app.

**Note**

After the Pre-launch reports came back, I noticed that all the devices that tested it show that it's working fine, but when I do it nothing happens. Could someone explain that too?

Comment: 1.) Remove cache from Google Play applications 2.)Set the correct date and time zone this might work for you.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work